# 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' in Assembly is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a property, which looks like below.

```
public ListItem[] DropDownListItems
        {
            get { return (ListItem[])ViewState["DropDownListItems"]; }
            set { ViewState["DropDownListItems"] = value; }
        }
```

And this is how i assign it values

```
ListItem[] litem = new ListItem[7];
litem[0] = new ListItem("View", "RowView");
litem[1] = new ListItem("ReadView", "RowReadView");
litem[2] = new ListItem("WriteView", "RowWriteView");
litem[3] = new ListItem("DeleteView", "RowDeleteView");
this.DropDownListItems=litem;
```

But I get the following error

**'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' in Assembly is not marked as serializable.**

How to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

In order to store a thing in the ViewState it must, but *must*, be serializable. Evidently, by the error message given, the type you're trying to push in there is not, in fact, serializable.

To resolve this you could create a wrapper, if you will, that encapsulates the data of the items which can then be translated to UI controls. This way you're also only storing the data that you need in the (already problematic) ViewState, too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you are trying to put a collection of ListItem into ViewState, and ViewState is serialized on the page as text, it is saying the Class ListItem is not serializable because they are not, you may have to use something else and do some post processing logic using Dictionary(Of String,string) for instance.